# Do uiviewcontrollers presented modally always need to be a child of uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

If I present a viewcontroller B from A and B never needs any kind of navigation (i.e. it's just a single viewcontroller that will never show anything itself) it is OK if B is not a child of a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to be a child of a navaigationController, but a navigation toolbar is a convenient place to put a 'cancel' or 'done' button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need a UINavigationController to do so.

Btw., what do you mean by *child of a UINavigationController*? You would never derive from UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd question because you would never have a ViewController be a child of a UINavigationController. You could embed a UIViewController in a UINavigationController, but this is completely optional.

It's all about whether you want to have a navigation bar without having to manually add it and such. You could add a navigation bar manually, but it is just more work.

When you are asking if it is "OK", I am not sure what you mean by this because whether or not you have one won't affect whether or not your program can run, but rather just how it looks and operates.

Comment: @shallowThought Ah, that's a typo I meant UINavigationController. I'll fix it now.